# Powershell script to delete the .bak files older than 30 days in all containers in one single script

Tags: azure, powershell, containers, blob

I am trying to use for loop for selecting all the containers using this script

```
param($TimerBlob)
    
 $CleanupTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)
 $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName **** -StorageAccountKey ****
$containername = @("mydbstore", "mydbstore2","mydbstore3")   # List of containers - 
For ($i=0; $i -lt $containername.Length; $i++) {
    
 Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containername[$i] -Context $context 
 Where-Object { $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $CleanupTime -and $_.BlobType -eq "PageBlob" -and $_.Name -like "*.bak"} |
 Remove-AzStorageBlob
}
```

The output lists all the files in all containers but doesn't delete them

Comment: Check your code. You need a pipe `|` after `-Context $context`.

Comment: Your cleanup time is one minute ago in the code, it's 30 days in the title.

Comment: yes i didn't added pipe by mistake but still same error is persisting

Comment: i used one minute ago as a test which can be changed to 30 days if its below script is working

Answer (score 0):

Curious, what is your output from the get-azstorageblob | ?{} without the pipe into remove-azstorageblob?
Are you getting a list of items that matches your filters?

Comment: yes only the list of containers in my storage account but its not deleting the files in those containers

Comment: Also if I add this '|'  at the getazstorageblob then it doesn't give any error or list of items and doesn't delete them either